# Error with spring security plugin in grails 2.4.0.M1

Tags: grails, spring-security

i'm running into a compilation issue, using grails 2.4.0.M1 and spring-security-core:2.0-RC2

this is the error:

> ..../target/work/plugins/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/ReflectionUtils.groovy:
>   205: Apparent variable 'org' was found in a static scope but doesn't
>   refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes: 
>   You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance
>   variable from a static context.  You misspelled a classname or
>   statically imported field. Please check the spelling.  You attempted
>   to use a method 'org' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by
>   the grammar.   @ line 205, column 18. 
>          application = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.application 
>                       ^

the problem seems to be around this method

```
private static GrailsApplication getApplication() { 
                if (!application) { 
                        application = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.application 
                } 
                application 
        }
```

on the class ReflectionUtils.groovy,

does anyone else as ran into something like this? if so how do you fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this today - https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/commit/ef3aab05bfb0eb2f2cbb2c5945f4fc9ca2f0697d

You can make the change that @Bubuntux showed as a temporary workaround, and I'll be releasing 2.0 final in a couple of weeks with this fixed. Hopefully you're not planning on using a Grails M1 release in production, so the delay shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: Thanks man!
i actually looked for the file on the git repo, hoping being able to submit a pull request with the change, unfortunately it was already there :(
anyways looking forward the release 2.0

Comment: btw i'm also running into an issue with the static rules (NPE)

Comment: Create an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE with a small test app that demonstrates the problem - run `grails bug-report` and attach that zip

Comment: Using spring-security-core-2.0-RC3 got rid of the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the ApplicationHolder class was deprecated a long time ago, and now removed on grals 2.4

so i just change the line

```
application = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.application
```

to

```
application = Holders.grailsApplication
```

Comment: lol. The actual meaning of deprecation. not like `Date.parse` in java. ;)